# Retrieve json property value in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created a simple logic app triggered by sending a json payload and I need to retrieve a value of a property in order to use it in a condition scope.

Thanks for you help

Comment: If the solution below provided by Frank helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). In Stack Overflow, we should mark the answer as "accepted" if it helps the problem. Then more communities are willing to help you in future, you can also get reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [Parse Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action, please click `Use sample payload to generate schema`, and then paste your json to generate the schema needed to parse the json:

[image]

Then select the key of the value you want to get

[image]

===============update=============================

I defined a json string as input.

[image]

According to the json string you provided, the generated schema should look like this：

```
{
    "properties": {
        "CusttId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Direction": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "MyId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Reason": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "TestDateTime": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

[image]

[image]

I did a test and it can retrieve `MyId`:

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing you said but the problem is that the variable don't take the value of my variable how can I solve this ? thanks for your help

Comment: In the `Parse Json` action, have you generated a schema?

Comment: Could you please provide a json example and tell me what value you want to get?

Comment: Sorry for my late response here is the json {
"CusttId":"TEST",
"TestDateTime":"2020-12-15T14:25:07.115Z",
"Direction":"Unknown",
"Reason":"Unknwon",
"MyId":"123456"
}
and need to get the value of MyId in order to use it to see if it is less or equal to 10

Comment: Do you have any other questions?